# Retornar nome pelo id na view. PHP e Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá!

No `controller` tenho o seguinte:

```
public function index() {
    $data['demandas'] = $this->demandas_model->get_demandas();

    $data['main_view'] = 'demandas/index';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
}
```

No `model` na função `get_demandas` tenho o seguinte:

```
public function get_demandas() {
    $query = $this->db->get('demandas');
    return $query->result();
}
```

E na `view` exibo da seguinte forma:

```
    <?php foreach($demandas as $demanda): ?>
                    <tr>
    <?php echo "<td><a href='". base_url()."index.php/demandas/edit_view/".           $demanda->da_id ."'>".$demanda->da_id."</a></td>" ?>
        <?php echo "<td>".$demanda->us_id."</td>" ?>
        <?php echo "<td>".$demanda->da_descricao."</td>" ?>
        <?php echo "<td>".$demanda->da_data."</td>" ?>
       // mais código
```

Onde está escrito `$demanda->us_id`, ao invés de exibir o código, preciso exibir o nome do usuário.

No model, na função `get_demandas`, me retorna o `id` e o `nome` do usuario preciso retornar através de outra chamada de outro model e colocar na `$data['demandas']`, mas não sei como colocar na view, através da `function index` do `controller`.

Esta é a `function` que me retorna os dados do usuario, do `model`:

```
public function get_usuario($id) {
    $this->db->where('us_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('usuarios');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Obrigado

Comment: `$demanda->nome`?

Comment: Eu esqueci de colocar outro detalhe, o id é uma chave estrangeira e através dele preciso retornar o nome de outra consulta

Comment: Faz um join aí.

Comment: Certo, esse join eu faço no get_demandas()? se fosse em sql eu faria, mas estou usando codeigniter e me confundo um pouco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que a solução é fazer um JOIN:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('demandas');
$this->db->join('outra_tabela', 'outra_tabela.campo_chave = demandas.id');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

Tem muito tempo que eu não uso o Codeigniter. Talvez valha a pena olhar a [documentação](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: obrigado! vou ver a documentação

Comment: +1 por não usar o CI, é boa prática :D

Comment: não usar o CI é boa prática?

Comment: @novato foi uma piada, entretanto existem opções melhores que o CI.

Comment: Qual me recomenda?

Comment: Laravel, Symfony, Lumen, Silex. Tem umas opções boas.